# Sveltekit - unable to import any file that starts with $app or $env

Tags: javascript, sveltekit

I'm not able to make use of ANY imports that include $app or $env or any path related variable inside a file that is created "outside" of SvelteKit.

Example:

socketio/server.ts

```
import * as FriendsService from '../src/lib/services/friends';
```

/services/friends.ts

```
import { JWT_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET } from "$env/static/private";
```

ERROR:

TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
../src/lib/services/friends.ts:2:41 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '$env/static/private' or its corresponding type declarations.

There's more information about the bug here:

https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/1485

I was wondering if anyone found a workaround this.

EDIT:

I assume there is a way of doing this, I'm running the server with command of ts-node, but instead of that I should make Vite see it somehow?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding `"extends": "./.svelte-kit/tsconfig.json"` in `tsconfig.json` :

```json
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
  ...
},
  "extends": "./.svelte-kit/tsconfig.json"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If some one still experienced same issue. Try to add:
"./.svelte-kit/ambient.d.ts" in your tsconfig.json. Example:

```json
{
    "extends": "./.svelte-kit/tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowJs": true,
        "checkJs": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        ...
    },
    "include": ["src/**/*", "./.svelte-kit/ambient.d.ts"],
}
```